# Permanently set specific brightness percentage for power plan

Tags: windows-10, laptop, brightness

I would like to set the screen brightness to a very specific percentage (let's say 82%, 23% and the like as examples).

Windows Mobility Center has a slider that shows the % as a tooltip when you click on it and drag, but it only shows as a tooltip. And it's not permanent.

On the other hand, when I right click on the battery icon in the taskbar and go to Power Options, the "Screen Brightness" slider at the bottom is permanent for the current power plan, but it does not show percentage.

So, how do I set a very specific percentage for the current power plan that is permanent?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to set screen brightness by percentage :

1. Open **Power Options**, and click on **Change plan settings** for your current power plan.
2. Click on **Change advanced power settings**
3. In your current active power plan's (ex: High Performance) advanced settings, expand **Display** and **Display brightness**
4. Change the brightness percentage to the level you want, and click on OK.

[image]

Comment: This setting is no longer available in Windows 10!